# DRF browsable api raw data placeholder

Tags: django-rest-framework

I'm new to DRF and I have a problem with the browsable API.
I would like to have an empty JSON already filled in "Content" of the "Raw Data" tab using regular APIView, so the user sees how should the request look like.

It works when I use CreateModelMixin, but I want to return something different than the whole model after creation or even have routes that only do some calculations without having any model underneeth.

```py
# serializers.py----------------------

class AnalysisSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    requestor = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='requestor.username')
    results = serializers.ReadOnlyField()
    class Meta:
        model = Analysis
        fields = ('requestor','text','results')


# views.py----------------------

class AnalysisRequest(APIView):
    """
    Request text analysis.
    """

    serializer_class = AnalysisSerializer

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = AnalysisSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            text = serializer.validated_data['text']
            results = analyze.analyze_text(text)
            serializer.save(requestor=request.user, results=results)
            return Response(results, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        else:
            return Response({'error': 'Invalid JSON received.'}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

For the example above I would like the browsable API to show the empty JSON in the Content field of the Raw data tab:

```
{
  "text": ""
}
```

Are there any simple methods to do that?

Comment: Have you solved this by any chance? I'd like to do the same.

Comment: still a question in 2022

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that worked for me (djangorestframework==3.14.0) after debugging.

The `class BrowsableAPIRenderer` tries to call `view.get_serializer()` so I simply added this to the view. (Changed to fit the question)

```
class AnalysisRequest(APIView):
    serializer_class = AnalysisSerializer

    def get_serializer():
        return self.serializer_class()
```

I also noted that OPTIONS also reacts and give a full description of the serializer in use.